# How to increase content of subreport?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, subreport

I have a main report and I add new a subreport for main. But have a problem. The width of the subreport is smaller than width of the main report. How to increase content of the subreport?

I use crystal report for visual studio 2010

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increase the width of the subreport itself. Right-click on the subreport, click edit subreport. Then increase the size of the subreport.

Comment: How to  increase the size of the subreport? I want to width of subreport as width of main report?

Comment: You format the subreport just like you would format the main report. Set the page width, set the size and location of the fields, etc. I'm not sure what you mean by 'I want to width of subreport as width of main report'. Maybe you can show a screenshot to let us know exactly what it looks like right now.

Comment: Please remember to mark answers as helpful or answered if they helped you solve your issue. If you found a different solution, please provide your own answer so others can benefit as well. Cheers!